# Better style to use bitwise vs comparison in certain cases?

Tags: optimization, comparison, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bitset

Just wondering if it's better style/more efficient to write code like this:

```
if (bitset[index] & 1)
{
//do something
}
```

vs:

```
if (bitset[index] == 1)
{
//do something
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: these two pieces of code are not equivalent

Comment: They both return 1 don't they?

Comment: no, first checks whether first bit is 1 and other - could be anything, second - checks that first bit is 1 and others are zero

Comment: I'm pretty sure they are equivalent - bitset[index] returns one bit and you can compare that bit with 1 which is just 0001 so it would return 1 if the bit is 1

Comment: set value of `bitset[index]` to 3 for example and compare

Comment: wouldn't that be undefined behavior?

Comment: depending on type of bitset variable

Comment: well since a bitset is basically a very compact array of bool, each index is either 0 or 1

Comment: array of bool = array of bytes, byte can hold 3, probably you have in mind c++ std::bitset?

Comment: yes exactly - std::bitset - I wanted to keep it language independent that's why

Comment: not all languages have bitset, anyway, if we're speaking about c++, then - both should be compiled into the same instruction (but in worst case 1st will be longer because of AND and then comparison), style wise - 2nd one is more readable and shows intent

Comment: Ok. That actually makes a lot of sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the above.  From the comments, you are talking about something like C++'s `std::bitset`, whose `operator[]` returns `bool`.  Normally, boolean values are only operated together with other boolean values, using boolean operations (`&&`, `||`, `!`, etc).  It seems strange to compare it with an object of another type (e.g. the integer 1), or to apply integer arithmetic operations like `& | + -` etc.  The conversion rules of the language let you do it, but it doesn't make as much logical sense.

So the most idiomatic, and also most compact, version would be:

```
if (bitset[index]) {
    // ...
}
```

If it makes more sense in context to think of the test as an equality comparison, then you can:

```
if (bitset[index] == true) {
    // ...
}
```

but to most C++ programmers this would simply look redundant.

This is all irrelevant from the standpoint of optimization; any reasonable compiler will realize that they are all equivalent and optimize them all the same.  In general, though, if you're doing something common, then you will usually get the best optimization by writing it in the most common and idiomatic way, as that is what the compiler is most likely to handle well.